# How do you make a `TextFormField` `prefixIcon` stay aligned at the top when `maxLines` is null?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a `TextFormField` that has an unbounded input field, in the sense where if the user hits the enter key the box can be infinitely expanded. However, it seems that the `prefixIcon` attribute is wrapped in a `Center`, so whenever the user hits Enter the icon is realigned to the center of the text box, making for a particularly weird experience.

I've been trying to keep that icon from moving but nothing seems to work.

This is my form field:

```
TextFormField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    style: theme.textTheme.body1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.description,
            color: theme.iconTheme.color,
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        hintText: 'Enter description'
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 11):

you can use `prefix:` as instead of `prefixIcon`.

```
TextFormField(
                  maxLines: null,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefix: Icon(Icons.email),
                      hintText: 'Enter description'),
                ),
```

Comment: The problem with this is, due to material guidelines, the prefix widget _only_ shows when the form field is in focus or if there is already text in the field. I want the icon to always show.

Answer (score 4):

I solved by adding padding to the prefixIcon

```
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
        child: Icon(
          icon,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: will not really work if the screen size of the cellphone changes --> because the padding then wont be the right one

Answer (score 0):

Another hack is that you can also add some padding to the top to allow the ICON to move downwards

```
 prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.email,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```